# How to make recent changes page inaccessible for anonymous users in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

There's a page: /index.php?title=Special:RecentChanges visible to every user authorized/unauthorised, is there a way to make this page inaccessible for anonymous users?

I've read this page already: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Recent_changes, but didn't find required information.

Comment: Disabling the special page will not guarantee secrecy of the recent changes. If you want to disable the special page for display reasons you can use something like the Lockdown extension.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Lockdown extension to achieve this

https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown

```
$wgSpecialPageLockdown['RecentChanges'] = [ 'user' ];
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, but it was `$wgSpecialPageLockdown['Recentchanges'] = [ 'user' ];`